# Поэлементное произведение обьектов типа Tensor в tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow

В tensorflow есть класс tensorflow::Tensor.
Для них не реализована операция operator*. 
Документация:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor
Как реализовать element wise произведение этих классов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поэлементное произведение выполняет операция [`Multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/multiply).

Эта операция определена в заголовочном файле `<math_ops.h>` и принимает три аргумента: область видимости (scope) и два множителя.

Пример создания узла, перемножающего `x` и `y`:

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
Scope myscope = root.NewSubScope("myscope"); // Создаём область видимости
...
auto z = Multiply(myscope, x, y);
...
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/192590)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, + за образцовое оформление.